# MySQL goes away executing a simple query

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have mysql server going away on a simple select query, the error is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (`increment_id` LIKE '%0005254')
```

This query is cron-scheduled and executed every 5 mins. If I restart the mysql server, the query is executing normally for a day and then starts crashing again.

I thought it's RAM-related, but I have plenty of RAM on the server:

[image: free]

The MySql version is 5.7.17 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

There are no errors neither in /var/log/mysql/errors.log nor in syslog

Some other configs:

```
max_allowed_packet = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
```

Do you have any idea what it can be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486023/sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-on-running-cron]

Answer (score 0):

Check the `open_files_limit`

```
  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%';
```

If less then increase it and check. Also would like to add `max_allowed_packet`

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet='figure more then existing one'.
```

Comment: The open_files_limit's value is 1024 now

Comment: Make it to `1024000`

Comment: Btw, how to set this variable? I've tried appending it into my.cnf but it doesn't help.

Comment: Just fire the query on your `mysql console`